# Knockout fail to bind drag and drop

Tags: jquery, data-binding, drag-and-drop, knockout.js

please take a look why I cant bind the drag and drop function. 
Refer to [my code here](http://jsfiddle.net/SimonYong/kV6nG/1/)
I have put some console log to track the flow and it seem to not event execute the bind event due to 'drag init' and 'drop init' is not printed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your `drag` and `drop` binding handlers prior to calling `ko.applyBindings`.  If Knockout encounters bindings that do not exist (they don't exist yet in your case), then it ignores them.

Comment: Not work. It come out with new error. I tried this ko.applyBinding then only bindingHandlers in my other page, it work perfect. So i don't think that is the problem

Comment: The reason that your `drag` and `drop` bindings are not being executed in your fiddle is definitely because your binding handlers are defined after you call applyBindings.  The fiddle also does not reference jQuery UI, which provides the drag/drop interactions.  You also are using a variable _dragType instead of _draggedType in the drop handler.  You are also checking for "Field" instead of "NewField" in the drop handler, although I am not sure what your end goal is for the functionality.  Here is a fiddle with just these items updated: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/kV6nG/2/